# GRU with Bahdanau Attention

Tags: bert-language-model, backpropagation, gru

I am building a custom model fusing pre-trained BERT embedding into GRU network and doing Bahdanau attention for classification task. I got stuck in the loss.backward() now, and I am suspecting the problem is related that the backprop doesn't work with the Bahdanau attention here. My model is consist of two levels. Please share your idea on this matter.

```
class BiGRU_Attention(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, dropout, batch_first,
                 bidirectional=True):
        super(BiGRU_Attention, self).__init__()
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.batch_first = batch_first
        self.dropout=nn.Dropout(p=dropout)
        self.bidrectional = bidirectional

        self.bi_gru = nn.GRU(input_size=input_size, hidden_size=hidden_size, num_layers=num_layers, 
                             batch_first=batch_first, dropout=dropout, bidirectional=bidirectional)
        
        self.W_h = nn.Linear(hidden_size*2, hidden_size*2)
        self.W_s = nn.Linear(hidden_size*2, hidden_size*2)
        self.v = nn.Linear(hidden_size*2, 1, bias=False)

        self.chunk_W_h = nn.Linear(hidden_size*2, hidden_size*2)
        self.chunk_W_s = nn.Linear(hidden_size*2, hidden_size*2)
        self.chunk_v = nn.Linear(hidden_size*2, 1, bias=False)
        
        # output size should be # class
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size*2, len(label_dict))

    def forward(self, input, target): 

        ############################ 1. Token-level Bahdanau Attention ########################
        batch_size, seq_len, _ = input.size()
        
        h_0 = torch.randn(torch.Size([2*self.num_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_size]))
        h_0 = h_0.to(device)
        output, h_n = self.bi_gru(input, h_0)

        output = output.view(batch_size, seq_len, 2, self.hidden_size)
        # print('[4] ', output.device)
        h_n = h_n.view(self.num_layers, 2, batch_size, self.hidden_size)

        # Up-sampling (384 * 2 = 768) by doing concatenation of forward/backward 
        output = torch.cat((output[:,:,-1,:], output[:,:,-2,:]), dim=2)
        h_n = torch.cat((h_n[-1,-1,:,:], h_n[-1,-2,:,:]), dim=1)    # 9개 chunk의 back/forward 정보 (아래 forward/ 위 backward)
      
        chunk_embedding_list = []
        for i in range(batch_size):
            attn_weights = torch.tanh(self.W_h(output[i]) + self.W_s(h_n[i]))
            attn_weights = self.v(attn_weights)
            attn_weights = torch.softmax(attn_weights, dim=0)
            
            chunk_embedding = torch.sum(attn_weights * output[i], dim=0)
            chunk_embedding_list.append(chunk_embedding)

        ############################ 2. Chunk-level Bahdanau Attention ########################
        chunk_input = torch.stack(chunk_embedding_list, dim=0)
        chunk_input = chunk_input.unsqueeze(0)
        chunk_batch_size = 1
        chunk_seq_len = batch_size
        chunk_h_0 = torch.randn(torch.Size([2*self.num_layers, chunk_batch_size, self.hidden_size]))
        chunk_h_0 = chunk_h_0.to(device)

        chunk_output, chunk_h_n = self.bi_gru(chunk_input, chunk_h_0)

        chunk_output = chunk_output.view(chunk_batch_size, chunk_seq_len, 2, self.hidden_size)
        chunk_h_n = chunk_h_n.view(self.num_layers, 2, chunk_batch_size, self.hidden_size)

        # Up-sampling (384 * 2 = 768) by doing concatenation of forward/backward 
        chunk_output = torch.cat((chunk_output[:,:,-1,:], chunk_output[:,:,-2,:]), dim=2)
        chunk_h_n = torch.cat((chunk_h_n[-1,-1,:,:], chunk_h_n[-1,-2,:,:]), dim=1)
       
        context_list = []
        for i in range(chunk_batch_size):
            attn_weights = torch.tanh(self.chunk_W_h(chunk_output[i]) + self.chunk_W_s(chunk_h_n[i]))
            attn_weights = self.chunk_v(attn_weights)
            attn_weights = torch.softmax(attn_weights, dim=0)
            context = torch.sum(attn_weights * chunk_output[i], dim=0)
            context = context.tolist()
            context_list.append(context)     
        
        context_tensor = torch.tensor(context_list)
        context_tensor = context_tensor.to(device)

        # Apply dropout
        context_tensor = self.dropout(context_tensor)
        
        # Compute final output
        loss_fn = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
        logit = self.fc(context_tensor)
        target_onehot = torch.eye(3).to(device)[target]  
        output = loss_fn(logit, target_onehot) 
        return output, logit

#############################   Hyper-parameters   #############################
from transformers import get_linear_schedule_with_warmup
from torch.optim import AdamW
optimizer = AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=1e-5, eps=1e-8)
epochs = 60
scheduler = get_linear_schedule_with_warmup(optimizer, num_warmup_steps=0,
                                            num_training_steps=len(dataloader_train)*epochs) 
                                            # For practice, length of dataloader_train is set to 3


########################### Train Module ######################################
for epoch in tqdm(range(1, epochs+1)):
    
    model.train()
    
    loss_train_total = 0

    progress_bar = tqdm(dataloader_train, desc='Epoch {:1d}'.format(epoch), leave=False, disable=False)
    for batch in progress_bar:
        model.zero_grad()
        batch = tuple(b.to(device) for b in batch)

        result_id, result_mask = chunk_partitioning(batch[0], batch[1])  
        bert_embed = BertEmbedding(result_id[0], result_mask[0])
        loss, _ = model(bert_embed, batch[2])

        loss_train_total += loss.item()
        loss.backward()

        torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), 1.0)

        optimizer.step()
        scheduler.step()
```

I tried to add another linear layer between chunk_embedding (1st level) and chunk_input (2nd level) but it was not the point. The problem is that the 'attn_weights' do not change by epochs during training. That means loss.backward() not working for learnable tensors like self.W_h ~ self.chunk_v.